# Chrome print preview cutting text off in the middle if it reaches the bottom margin of the page

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

When printing on Chrome, my page (*top and bottom*) margins are **cutting the text in half**. On my `print.css` I defined:

```
@page {
    size: letter;
    size: 8.5in 11in;
    margin: 20cm 2cm;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Cannot find a possible solution to fix this bug. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 margin: 20cm 2cm;
```

Your top and bottom margins are 20cm each (7.8in) on paper that is 11 inches high. That doesn't make sense. Did you mean `20mm` (2cm) margin?